# Redirect not found pages

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, redirection

In apache,
 How I can redirected the pages not found to / ?

```
Not Found

The requested URL /dsadsa was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Would serve up the content of / at the URL entered. OTOH is you explicitly want to redirect the user then something like...

```
ErrorDocument 404 /goback.html
```

...and in go back.html...

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [**FallbackResource**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource)